# Let be $\phi$ the Frobenius morphism, why $1-\phi$ is separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let be $C$ an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. We know that the Frobenius morphism $\phi:C\longrightarrow C$ is inseparable, i.e, $K(C)/\phi^*K(C) = K(C)/K(C)^q$ is an inseparable extension.

How can i show that $1-\phi$ is separable?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the action of a morphism on the module of differentials $\Omega_C$? Also, is your curve $C$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$? Otherwise $1$ and $\phi$ don't have the same codomain.

Comment: @RichardD.James Yes, my curve is an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. It is said in the proof of Hasse Theorem. And about your firts answer ... i don't know

Comment: @RichardD.James could you recomend me a reference about the action of a morphism on $\Omega_C$?

Comment: Crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361086/let-phi-be-the-frobenius-morphism-why-is-1-phi-separable).

Comment: This is covered in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Corollary III.5.5. It relies on Proposition II.4.2.

Comment: @RichardD.James Thank you very much!!!